# Word Sorting in Batch

Tags: sorting, batch-file

Right let me rewrite this try to make it more clear.

Picture added to make this even clearer:
[image]
I have two files

1. File 1, contains words.
2. file 2, contains commands.

I need to put words from FILE 1
into FILE 2

I cannot copy-paste them one by one, because there is a LOT of words in **FILE 1**

- File 1 is listed in alphabetical order (by first letter)
- File 2 the command does not change

The issue is getting words from **file 1** into **file 2**

but they have to be moved into quotes " " in **file 2**

so a script that could for example..
Take `apple` from **file 1** and move it between quotes `admin.executemotecommand "apple"`inside **file 2** as it goes down the list keeping the words in order as they move them across.

This could perhaps be done the same way around in which, the script writes the command in front of the words in **file 1** as it goes down **file 1's** list

Is this even possible? I've never seen this done anywhere else and completely clueless if batch is even the right language for it.

Comment: Acid & Diamonds... I expected Lucy instead of Charlie...

Comment: "are in alphabetical order"? which alphabet are you using?

Comment: `for /f %%i in (file.txt) do echo execute."%%i"` (use `%i` instead of `%%i` when using on the command prompt)

Comment: Is this a one time job? If so, you might use a macro in Notepad++

Comment: Where do you need the command to be executed ??

Comment: @Stephan, you should also add a `"delims="` option following the `/f` of your `for` shell command.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: And what have you tried, anyway? Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Adi, I personally am not even sure if batch is a decent language capable of this.

Comment: Let explain further...
I need to have a script that can take:
Alpha 
Bravo
Charlie
from file.txt
and move it to
Command.txt
the condition is that once in command.txt, it needs to be sorted automatically and placed after (already existing) commands.

e.g:
Admin.remoteexecute ""
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie 
Will need to put between the quotes "" on command: admin.execute
so.. 
admin.remoteexecute "alpha"
admin.remoteexecute "Bravo"
admin.remoteexecute "Charlie"

Comment: @GolezTrol Actually, the macro is the best idea I've seen..
Only issue is.. the list is about 10 thousand words that need to be moved over and the words differ day to day, so a macro would only work once... sadly..

Comment: first step: add the needed words with `for` (see above). Second step, sort the resulting file with `sort`

Comment: @Stephan done all of that..

`title Sort
for /f delims= %i ::in? alpha.txt
pause >nul`

My knowledge of batch is very limited.. i'm trying to piece together what you mean, perhaps I've really used the wrong website for this haha.

Comment: create a new question and post what you coded so far. This question is on hold, because it's hard to understand and there seems to be no attempt from you.

Comment: @Cinn I personally am sure that batch is ***not*** a decent language. Not even close. I only have a vague idea, still, of what exactly you're trying to do, but it's very likely that you *can* do it in batch, somehow. You can do it in assembler, too. But I don't recommend it. Anyway, rather than trying to clarify in a running conversation in comments, you should edit the question to include all the explanations, code, and examples in an organized fashion.

Comment: @Stephan Creating a new question is not the right way to go about it, in fact the new question would be closed as a duplicate. This question should be edited to make it clearer. If a question is edited after it's on hold or closed, it automatically goes into the Reopen Votes review queue.

Comment: @AdiInbar Re-edited to be more clear.

Comment: Oh, for Pete's sake - it's a one-liner. From the prompt, `FOR /F "DELIMS=" %A in (yourfileofwords) DO >>outfilename ECHO whateverwhatever "%A"` . If you want to run it as a line in a batch file, double each `%`. End. Done and dusted.

Comment: @Magoo I'm not sure sure. He's not saying that he wants to create a *new* file by taking the words from a list and adding some fixed text around each. He's saying that he already *has* a file with commands and quotation marks, and wants to *insert* the words listed in the first file into the commands in the second file, but he doesn't seem to know how to express what he wants to do clearly. The linked image shows a command file that has the exact same command repeated, but he didn't actually state that it will always be the same, and his first version of the question indicates otherwise.

Comment: Also, it's not clear how words in the first file are to be matched to commands in the second file. Is it based on corresponding line numbers, i.e. the first word goes into the first command, the second word into the second command, etc.? If so, does that mean that the two files have an identical number of lines? Again, the first version of the question implies otherwise. In his original example, each word is added to multiple commands (which in the example are the same two for each word, but he doesn't actually *say* that).

Comment: This question is one vote away from being reopened, but I think it should be left closed until these things are clarified.

Comment: @AdiInbar Yes, there is exactly the same amount of words as commands down the list. 
I did state the command stays the same, it never changes once, only thing that's different is the words in the word file.

Comment: Well, you said "the command doesn't change", but I found that ambiguous in context, because in the original explanation you gave an example in which each word was added to two commands (execute."word" and command."word"). But if the command file just has the exact same text repeated over and over, is there any reason you need to create the command file first and add the words to it, rather than just using the word list to *create* the command file, as the code in Magoo's comment would do? Based on what you're saying here, it sounds like that would be sufficient.

Comment: @AdiInbar I don't think anyone quite understands what I need yet, I figured it was relatively easy to understand.
perhaps I'm confused as to what Magoo's code is doing.

I must have misinterpreted the use of this site, I am not a batch programmer, more or less my original question was "Can this be done?" my intent was to then move to a different site to get an answer but people seem to have assumed I wanted them to write code for me, and instead I've been given code I have no idea how to use Magoo's code.

`FOR /F "DELIMS=" 
%A in (words.txt) DO >>outfilename ECHO (WhatIsWhatever?) "%A"`

Comment: This site is a Q&A resource for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers. So, "Can this be done?" or "can anyone suggest strategies for approaching this problem?" are off-topic, but "*How* can this be done? Here's what I've tried and it doesn't work because..." is on-topic. However, it's not entirely clear what "this" is in this case.

Comment: I explained to you what Magoo's code does. It takes a list of words from a file and creates a new file that places each word in quotation marks after a given string (such as the name of a command) that is always the same (`whatever "apple"`, `whatever "acid"`, `whatever "diamond"`, etc. given "whatever" as the fixed string (i.e., the command) and the word list from your original example). Based on your response to me, that's what you're looking for. Did you *try* it?

Comment: @AdiInbar 

`FOR /F "DELIMS=" %A in alpha.txt DO >>output ECHO admin.eanbleremoteadmin "%A%"`

Was tried, no result, didn't create a new file, did not move anything from the worded file to the command file between the quotes.

Comment: @AdiInbar 

`FOR /F "DELIMS=" %A in alpha.txt DO >>output ECHO admin.eanbleremoteadmin "%A%"`

Was tried, no result, didn't create a new file, did not move anything from the worded file to the command file between the quotes.

Most likely due to me misunderstanding the code.

tried many variations after `>>` like `>>something.txt` `>>outfilename` `>>something` still don't know what goes there.

Comment: For one thing, the parentheses around the filename are required. Also, you added a trailing `%` after the second `%A`, which is incorrect. However, it looks like I read his code too quickly. What I explained is what that code is *intended* to do, but on a closer look I see that it has multiple syntax errors and a redundancy. This is getting excessive for comments, but based on your responses I think I can infer that it's not important to edit an existing command file, and creating a new one is sufficient. I'll reopen the question and answer it.

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said about the multiple syntax errors, because it looks like two were changes that you made, and apparently you *can* place the redirection after the **DO** (i.e. `DO >> commands.txt (ECHO ...` works). I wasn't aware that you can do that. However, `"DELIMS="` is not necessary if you have one word on each line. What that does is assign multiple space-separated words on the same line to the variable in each iteration. `TOKENS=*` would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little confusing, but based on your responses in the comments my understanding is that you don't necessarily need the script to edit a preexisting **file 2**, because you're repeating the same command(s) for each word, so the script can just create a new file based on the words in **file 1**.

You can do it at the prompt like this:

```
FOR /F %a IN (words.txt) DO ECHO admin.executeremotecommand "%a" >> commands.txt
```

The original version of the question indicated that you want more than one command for each word. I take it you changed that in order to simplify that question, and figured you'd just run the script once for each command? However, it's quite simple to have it produce more than one command for each word:

```
FOR /F %a IN (words.txt) DO (ECHO first.command "%a" & ECHO second.command "%a") >> commands.txt
```

In a batch file, you'd do it this way:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%a IN (words.txt) DO (
  ECHO first.command "%%a"
  ECHO second.command "%%a"
) >> commands.txt
```

BTW, in the code in some of your comments, you surrounded the variable with %'s (`%A%`). That's incorrect; it would evaluate to the value of **%A** followed by a literal **%**. Surrounding with %'s is used only for environment variables. (Note that the %'s around environment variables do *not* get doubled in a batch file. For example, to get the current date, use `ECHO %date%` both at the prompt and in a batch file.)

Comment: Adi.. you are a god send..
You just saved me a lot of work, this file will help me a lot in future, thank you.

Comment: If I wanted to add a separate command(s) under the current command is that possible with a simple edit?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If you mean more than two commands for each word, just add `& ECHO another.command "%a" & ECHO yet-another-command "%a"` etc. in the prompt version, and more lines like `ECHO third.command "%%a"` in the batch version. If you mean that you want the first command for each word, followed by the second command for each word rather than all commands for one word and then all commands for another word, you could either repeat the loop for each command or use nested loops. If you can clarify what you're asking I can give an example.

Comment: Oh I kind of just hacked it together.

`@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%a IN (Words.txt) DO (
  ECHO admin.enableremoteadmin %%a
  ECHO admin.execremotecommand "admin.displayname 1"
) >> out.bat`

And this works good, takes a long time for the computer to process the amount of text though, haha.